# getNameByAlias removed in Ext JS 5

Tags: extjs, extjs4, backwards-compatibility, extjs7

Currently a Ext JS 4 uses getNameByAlias of https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager in its code to map database dynamic alias configurations to class matching to it.

Application needs to upgrade Ext JS. In Ext JS 5 method was removed. Having an extjs alias, is there a dynamic way by code to determine the matching implementation class?

Ext.define('classNameIneed',
extends: ...,
alias: 'aliasIhave',
....

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Ext.ClassManager.getNameByAlias` in ExtJs5.
Its [definition](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.Inventory.html#method-getNameByAlias) got moved to `Ext.Inventory`.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but should do the trick.

Ext.getclassName(Ext.createByAlias('aliasIhave')}